# Let $p$ be prime and suppose $P,Q$ are both $p$-subgroups of a group $G$. Show that $Q\leq N_G(P)$ implies that $QP$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P).$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Here is the problem statement.

> Let $p$ be a prime number and suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are both $p$-subgroups of some group $G$. Show that $Q\leq N_G (P)$ implies that $QP$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G (P).$

My idea would be let $h\in QP$ so that $h=qr$ for some $q\in Q$ and $r\in P$. Then $|q|=p^m$ and $|r|=p^k$ for some $m$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, my intuition tells me that $|h|=p^{m+k}$ but that would require $q$ and $r$ to commute. Also, I wouldn't have used the given fact that $Q\leq N_G(P)$ which I am assuming is there for a reason.

Any hints in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, my intuition tells me that $|h|=p^{m+k}$ but that would require $q$ and $r$ to commute

Even if they did commute it wouldn't imply $|h|$ is that big. For one thing, there's no assumption that $Q$ and $P$ intersect trivially, so if (for instance) $r=q^{-1}$ then $qr$ has order $1$!

The *first* thing you want to prove is that $QP=\{qr\mid q\in Q,r\in P\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ in the first place. To do that you will need to use the fact that $Q\le N_G(P)$. (Note for this part the fact that $P$ and $Q$ are $p$-groups is irrelevant.) *Second* you want to show $QP$ is a subset of $N_G(P)$.

After that you can show $QP$ has $p$-power order. Note its order is the product of $[QP:P]$ and $|P|$, and there is a little trick $[QP:P]=[Q:P\cap Q]$...

Comment: Would I not need to show that $QP$ is a \textit{subgroup} of $N_G (P)$? Why does simply showing its a subset suffice?

Comment: If you show it's a subgroup of $G$ contained in $N_G(P)$ then ... it's a subgroup of $N_G(P)$. I said show $QP$ is a subgroup *first*. (Although you could show it's a subset of $N_G(P)$ first, it doesn't really matter.)

Comment: Also, don't those last equalities assume that G is finite?

Comment: Nope. You can say $|QP|=|QP/P|\cdot|P|$ and $|QP/P|=|Q/P\cap Q|$ for infinite cardinals too (in fact, that last one doesn't even require $QP$ to be a subgroup).